# Rectangle custom object shows zero width, should be non-zero

Tags: java

I wrote a Rectangle class that has length and width for the fields. setLength, setWidth, getLength, getWidth, getPerimeter, and getArea for the methods. In my main program, RectangleTest; when I run it; I am able to enter in the length and width. The program then displays the value that I entered in for length (which is correct), but when it displays the value that I entered in for width; it always displays 0.0. Please help. Here is the source code:

```
package com.delgado;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class RectangleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double length;
        double width;
        String input;
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");

        input = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Please enter the length of the basketball court: ");
        length = Double.parseDouble(input);
        input = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Please enter the width of the basketball court: ");
        width = Double.parseDouble(input);
        Rectangle basketBall = new Rectangle(length, width);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null,
                "You entered " + formatter.format(basketBall.getLength())
                        + " for the length, and "
                        + formatter.format(basketBall.getWidth())
                        + " for the width.");

    }

}
```

If you need the source code for the Rectangle class, please let me know. Thank you guys.

Here is the source code for the Rectangle class:

```
package com.delgado;

/* This Class creates an object that takes the length and width as arguments,
 * and returns the perimeter and area of a rectangle.
 */

public class Rectangle {

    private double length; // Holds the length.
    private double width; // Holds the width.

    /**
     * This is a default constructor
     */

    public Rectangle() {

    }

    /**
     * This is a constructor that takes two arguments; len and w.
     * 
     * @param len
     *            The length of the rectangle.
     * @param w
     *            The width of the rectangle.
     */
    public Rectangle(double len, double w) {
        length = len;
        w = width;
    }

    /**
     * The method setLength sets the length of a rectangle.
     * 
     * @param len
     *            The length of a rectangle.
     */

    public void setLength(double len) {
        length = len;
    }

    /**
     * The method setWidth sets the width of a rectangle.
     * 
     * @param w
     *            The width of a rectangle.
     */
    public void setWidth(double w) {
        width = w;
    }

    /**
     * The method getLength returns the length of a rectangle.
     * 
     * @return Returns the length of a rectangle.
     */
    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    /**
     * The method getWidth returns the width of a rectangle.
     * 
     * @return Returns the width of a rectangle.
     */
    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * The method getArea returns the area of a rectangle.
     * 
     * @return Returns the area of a rectangle.
     */
    public double getArea() {
        return length * width;
    }

    /**
     * The method getPerimeter returns the perimeter of a rectangle.
     * 
     * @return Returns the perimeter of a rectangle.
     */
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (length * 2) + (width * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: "My Code Won't Display Correct Input" is a really useless title. Please descibe your issue properly.

Comment: Yes, you should post the Rectangle class.

Comment: @EdwinTorres: there is a Java core class called Rectangle that it looks like he's using.

Comment: Okay, but then his constructor is wrong.

Comment: @EdwinTorres: my apologies, you are right: He is in fact shooting himself in the foot with his own Rectangle constructor.

Comment: Yeah, other methods are not working. This is not java.awt.Rectangle

Comment: What is wrong with my constructors? I was instructed to overload my constructors using a default constructor and one that takes arguments?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What is wrong with my constructors? I was instructed to overload my constructors using a default constructor and one that takes arguments?

Comment: @JasonDelgado: I pointed out your constructor error in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to wonder if your JOptionPane is messing with your Scanner... can't tell til I test it, but regardless, I would simplify things even further. As long as you're showing JOptionPanes, who not show one that displays a message **and** gets input at the same time?

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(....)
```

---

Edit: **Yikes**

```
public Rectangle(double len, double w) {
    length = len;
    w = width;
}
```

You're setting the w parameter here, not the width field!!! Instead it should be:

```
   width = w; //*********
```

Do you understand why?

Comment: @JasonDelgado: yep Edwin Torres was right. You're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Yikes indeed, problem with re-inventing wheels

Comment: Thank @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, that was the problem.